# Does anybody know any web hosts that cater for gmail forwarding?

Tags: domains, gmail

Our organisation currently relies on setting up forwarders with our web host to direct emails sent to (e.g.) @organisation.com to and from gmail accounts. While our current web host allows the option to set up forwarders, we have frequent issues with all our emails bouncing, and the host has warned us that their forwarders are not designed to send outside their servers.

Does anybody know of any alternatives that would allow us to continue forwarding to and from gmail without having to use a client like Google Snatch, which would be problematic for us? Thank you.

Comment: If you use Gmail have a look at Google Apps https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/products/gmail/ service and you will not have to forward your mail anymore, Gmail will be literally running on your @organisation.com, it is quite easy to setup. Another way is to setup your own mail server, but to make it cheap, it requires basic knowledge of Linux administration. This question should not have been closed, as it is specific and it does not relate to finding hosting.